# Laravel helper page loading slow

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I hava helper class and have functions:

```
  static public function getPRBcurr(){
    $currency = Cache::get('currency_prb_ee_agroTimeout');
    if($currency) return $currency;

    $contentCurrency = self::file_get_contents_curl(
        'https://www.agroprombank.com/xmlinformer.php'
    );

    if(!$contentCurrency) {
        $_currency = Storage::get('currency_prb_agro');
        Cache::put('currency_prb_agroTimeout', $_currency, 60);
        return $_currency;
    }

    $xmls = simplexml_load_string( $contentCurrency );

    $currency = (string)$xmls->course[1]->currency[5]->currencySell;
    $currency = ($currency > 0) ? $currency : null;
    $currency = (strpos($currency, '1.0') !== false) ? '0.99' : $currency;

    Cache::put('currency_prb_agroTimeout', $currency, 720);
    Storage::put('currency_prb_agro', $currency);
    return $currency;
}

static function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 500);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

And I have a product.blade:

```
<div class="price-prb">
            <span itemprop="price">
                @php
                    $prb = intval($product->price * Helper::getPRBcurr());
                @endphp
                {{ $prb }}
                <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="PRB"> {!! trans_choice('messages.currency.RUB', $prb) !!}</span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

When I go to category, where all products (890 products), page loading slow. If I remove `Helper::getPRBcurr()` all is good. How I can fix this problem? Problem in function `file_get_contents_curl 500ms timeout`.

Comment: You should use Ajax to load the data from the API.

Comment: I use Ajax, but I wait 3-5 secs. When I Remove Helper::getPRBcur() all is good.

Comment: `$prb = intval($product->price * Helper::getPRBcurr());` this is not ajax. This is php executing in your view file.

Comment: @Jadasdas That's totally normal, you are using curl requests to third party which takes alot of time from the 890 products.

I suggest to use multi-threading or divide the showing of the 890 products 10 by 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Helper::getPRBcurr()` directly with the view file is a bad idea. The function must fully complete before the page with render, hence the slow loading. Moving it to an asychronous call will render the page quickly and then wait for the data to fetch, which is a much better user experience.

Comment: How I can do it?

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript, presumably jQuery, raw XHR, fetch, axios... whichever javascript library you are familiar with really.

Comment: Are you certain it's not working? You have a lot going on in that single function. Caching, writing to storage, external http requests, xml loading... I'm not surprised all that takes 3-5 seconds as you mentioned.

Comment: I need rewrite function and use ajax?

Comment: Refactoring that function into well defined smaller functions would certainly not be a bad idea. Ajax however is what the client would use to call `getPRBcurr` instead of having this `$prb = intval($product->price * Helper::getPRBcurr());` execute prior to page load. It may not necessarily get your data faster, but the page will load much faster and you can display a busy indicator while the ajax request does it's thing. Much better than a blank white page and a spinning icon in the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this method call is always slow is because your cache is not working. The cache key you're reading is different from the one you're storing, so in effect you're always running a HTTP request, every time.

```
$currency = Cache::get('currency_prb_ee_agroTimeout');
```

And when setting the cache:

```
Cache::put('currency_prb_agroTimeout', $currency, 720);
```

Notice the keys are different, `currency_prb_ee_agroTimeout` vs `currency_prb_agroTimeout`.

However, as mentioned in the answer given by @btl running a HTTP request when serving a request will lead to a bad user experience and you should use AJAX to load in the result. By both fixing your caching issue and implementing this, everything would function significantly faster.